# angular-translate not working in a button that has another component

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

angular-translate works fine for several p's, h's, and labels using the format

```
<p translate>something</p>
```

Its great. But I can not get it working on buttons that have another Angular component on that button, specifically angular-dropdowns. In fact, when I put translate at the end of the > , it breaks the entire page on page load and no Javascript works. In the Console, I get Error: [$compile:multidir] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/$compile/multidir (etc., etc.)

The HTML is

```
<div id="leftOfMap" class="floatingSection" data-ng-controller="languageController">
    <ul>
        <li class="leftOfMapItem"><button id="languageButton" dropdown-menu="ddMenuOptions" dropdown-model="ddMenuSelected" class="btn-menu">Language</button></li>
        <li class="leftOfMapItem" translate>BIKE PATHS</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The Angular controller for that button is

```
residenceApp.controller('languageController', [ '$scope', 'changeLanguage',
function( $scope, changeLanguage ) {
var languageChoices = [
    {"text": "English", "val": "en"},
    {"text": "Espanol", "val": "es"}
];
$scope.ddMenuOptions = languageChoices;
$scope.ddMenuSelected = {};
$scope.$watch('ddMenuSelected', function(newVal) {
    if (newVal && newVal.text) {
        changeLanguage(newVal.val); //eg., changeLanguage(es);
        //changeLanguage() is the name of a factory service
    }
}, true);
}]);
```

The dropdown button works, selects languages and translation occurs. myApp has the config stuff that is in angular-translate's docs - $translateProvider.translations() kind of stuff. Again, the problem is that when the translate attribute/instruction is on the button, it breaks the whole page on page load. I tried bringing $translate into the above controller, but could not get it working. What has to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using an older version of Angular Translate than the current version on Github? Because if not, that's not the right syntax for it. Use one of the following:

```
<li class="leftOfMapItem" translate="BIKE PATHS"></li>
```

or:

```
<li class="leftOfMapItem">{{ 'BIKE PATHS' | translate }}</li>
```

Note the quotes around the translation key in the expression.

Comment: I'm using the latest angular-translate 2.2.0. I tried the translate= format. It also breaks the page. The latest docs suggest the format I'm using - for performance reasons. Thanks, though.

Comment: If you don't need to actually change languages on the fly (most of the time you're loading from a preferences list, and you don't mind reloading if the preference changes), try the last format, but with one change: `<li class="leftOfMapItem">{{ :: 'BIKE PATHS' | translate }}</li>`. This works great and doesn't have a performance issue because it doesn't need a watcher. I also personally find it a little easier to read - YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - got it working. Turns out that the double colons break the page, also, but your original second suggestion {{ 'LANGUAGE' | translate }} works.

Comment: :: is only allowed in the latest Angular, I think from 1.3.14 and up was when it was introduced. It's not necessary - just a little performance tweak. It will eliminate one watcher.

Comment: Thanks, again. I'm at 1.2.21. When 1.3.x goes to stable, I'll try the ::  I've made a note to myself.